# Is there a downside to cheating in Disgaea D2?

Tags: disgaea-d2

Disgaea D2 introduced a Cheat Vendor that lets you adjust things like EXP/Mana/HL gain.

Is there a downside to using this menu? Does the game's levelling curve expect me to be using it, or is it purely optional?